# Fix error when using makefile outside of CubeIDE

Tags: makefile, embedded, stm32cubeide

We are building an stm32 project based on STM32CubeIDE, when using the IDE to build and run it works fine, it displays in the inbuilt console,

```
make -j12 all 
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/portable/MemMang/heap_4.c" -mcpu=cortex-m7 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DNucleo=8000000UL -DBoard=25000000UL -DHSE_VALUE=Nucleo -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32H723xx -DDATA_IN_D2_SRAM -c -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB" -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32H7xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Models" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/ST-LIB_LOW" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/ST-LIB_HIGH" -I../LWIP/App -I../LWIP/Target -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/system -I../Drivers/BSP/Components/lan8742 -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/netif/ppp -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/lwip -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/lwip/apps -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/lwip/priv -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/lwip/prot -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/netif -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/posix -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/posix/arpa -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/posix/net -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/posix/sys -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/stdc -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/system/arch -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services/Communication" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services/Communication/Ethernet" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services/Communication/Ethernet/UDP" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services/Communication/Ethernet/TCP" -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/include -I../Middlewares/Third_Party -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -fcyclomatic-complexity -MMD -MP -MF"Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/portable/MemMang/heap_4.d" -MT"Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/portable/MemMang/heap_4.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv5-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/portable/MemMang/heap_4.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F/port.c" -mcpu=cortex-m7 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DNucleo=8000000UL -DBoard=25000000UL -DHSE_VALUE=Nucleo -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32H723xx -DDATA_IN_D2_SRAM -c -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB" -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32H7xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Models" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/ST-LIB_LOW" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/ST-LIB_HIGH" -I../LWIP/App -I../LWIP/Target -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/system -I../Drivers/BSP/Components/lan8742 -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/netif/ppp -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/lwip -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/lwip/apps -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/lwip/priv -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/lwip/prot -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/netif -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/posix -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/posix/arpa -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/posix/net -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/posix/sys -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/stdc -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/system/arch -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services/Communication" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services/Communication/Ethernet" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services/Communication/Ethernet/UDP" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services/Communication/Ethernet/TCP" -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/include -I../Middlewares/Third_Party -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -fcyclomatic-complexity -MMD -MP -MF"Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F/port.d" -MT"Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F/port.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv5-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F/port.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/croutine.c" -mcpu=cortex-m7 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DNucleo=8000000UL -DBoard=25000000UL -DHSE_VALUE=Nucleo -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32H723xx -DDATA_IN_D2_SRAM -c -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB" -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32H7xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Models" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/ST-LIB_LOW" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/ST-LIB_HIGH" -I../LWIP/App -I../LWIP/Target -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/system -I../Drivers/BSP/Components/lan8742 -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/netif/ppp -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/lwip -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/lwip/apps -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/lwip/priv -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/lwip/prot -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/netif -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/posix -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/posix/arpa -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/posix/net -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/posix/sys -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/stdc -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/system/arch -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services/Communication" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services/Communication/Ethernet" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services/Communication/Ethernet/UDP" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services/Communication/Ethernet/TCP" -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/include -I../Middlewares/Third_Party -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -fcyclomatic-complexity -MMD -MP -MF"Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/croutine.d" -MT"Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/croutine.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv5-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/croutine.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/event_groups.c" -mcpu=cortex-m7 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DNucleo=8000000UL -DBoard=25000000UL -DHSE_VALUE=Nucleo -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32H723xx -DDATA_IN_D2_SRAM -c -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB" -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32H7xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Models" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/ST-LIB_LOW" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/ST-LIB_HIGH" -I../LWIP/App -I../LWIP/Target -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/system -I../Drivers/BSP/Components/lan8742 -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/netif/ppp -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/lwip -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/lwip/apps -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/lwip/priv -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/lwip/prot -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/netif -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/posix -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/posix/arpa -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/posix/net -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/posix/sys -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/stdc -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/system/arch -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services/Communication" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services/Communication/Ethernet" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services/Communication/Ethernet/UDP" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services/Communication/Ethernet/TCP" -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/include -I../Middlewares/Third_Party -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -fcyclomatic-complexity -MMD -MP -MF"Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/event_groups.d" -MT"Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/event_groups.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv5-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/event_groups.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/list.c" -mcpu=cortex-m7 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DNucleo=8000000UL -DBoard=25000000UL -DHSE_VALUE=Nucleo -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32H723xx -DDATA_IN_D2_SRAM -c -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB" -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32H7xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Models" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/ST-LIB_LOW" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/ST-LIB_HIGH" -I../LWIP/App -I../LWIP/Target -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/system -I../Drivers/BSP/Components/lan8742 -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/netif/ppp -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/lwip -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/lwip/apps -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/lwip/priv -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/lwip/prot -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/netif -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/posix -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/posix/arpa -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/posix/net -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/posix/sys -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/stdc -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/system/arch -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services/Communication" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services/Communication/Ethernet" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services/Communication/Ethernet/UDP" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services/Communication/Ethernet/TCP" -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/include -I../Middlewares/Third_Party -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -fcyclomatic-complexity -MMD -MP -MF"Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/list.d" -MT"Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/list.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv5-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/list.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/queue.c" -mcpu=cortex-m7 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DNucleo=8000000UL -DBoard=25000000UL -DHSE_VALUE=Nucleo -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32H723xx -DDATA_IN_D2_SRAM -c -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB" -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32H7xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Models" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/ST-LIB_LOW" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/ST-LIB_HIGH" -I../LWIP/App -I../LWIP/Target -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/system -I../Drivers/BSP/Components/lan8742 -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/netif/ppp -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/lwip -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/lwip/apps -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/lwip/priv -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/lwip/prot -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/netif -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/posix -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/posix/arpa -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/posix/net -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/posix/sys -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include/compat/stdc -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/system/arch -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services/Communication" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services/Communication/Ethernet" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services/Communication/Ethernet/UDP" -I"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Inc/HALAL/Services/Communication/Ethernet/TCP" -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/include -I../Middlewares/Third_Party -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -fcyclomatic-complexity -MMD -MP -MF"Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/queue.d" -MT"Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/queue.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv5-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/queue.o"
```

and more gibberish and warnings and so, but I don't want to flood the post :)

The thing is we are trying to automate the build process to improve our CI/CD so I was working on a script that given the configuration [Debug | Release] navigates to that directory and runs make.
When running

```make
make -j12 all
```

from the script the following error shows:

```shell
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-fcyclomatic-complexity'
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-fcyclomatic-complexity'
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-fcyclomatic-complexity'
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-fcyclomatic-complexity'
make: *** [Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/subdir.mk:37: Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/event_groups.o] Error 1
make: *** [Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F/subdir.mk:19: Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F/port.o] Error 1
make: *** [Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/subdir.mk:37: Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/list.o] Error 1
make: *** [Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/subdir.mk:37: Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/croutine.o] Error 1
make: *** [Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/subdir.mk:37: Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/timers.o] Error 1
make: *** [Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/subdir.mk:37: Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/stream_buffer.o] Error 1
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-fcyclomatic-complexity'
make: *** [Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/netif/ppp/subdir.mk:91: Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/netif/ppp/ccp.o] Error 1
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-fcyclomatic-complexity'
make: *** [Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/netif/ppp/subdir.mk:91: Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/netif/ppp/auth.o] Error 1
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-fcyclomatic-complexity'
make: *** [Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/netif/ppp/subdir.mk:91: Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/netif/ppp/chap-md5.o] Error 1
```

If instead in the script I write `make -j12´ the following is outputted to the console:

```shell
rm -rf ./Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/portable/MemMang/heap_4.cyclo ./Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/portable/MemMang/heap_4.d ./Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/portable/MemMang/heap_4.o ./Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/portable/MemMang/heap_4.su
rm -rf ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/apps/tftp/tftp_server.cyclo ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/apps/tftp/tftp_server.d ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/apps/tftp/tftp_server.o ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/apps/tftp/tftp_server.su
rm -rf ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/apps/sntp/sntp.cyclo ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/apps/sntp/sntp.d ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/apps/sntp/sntp.o ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/apps/sntp/sntp.su
rm -rf ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/apps/mqtt/mqtt.cyclo ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/apps/mqtt/mqtt.d ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/apps/mqtt/mqtt.o ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/apps/mqtt/mqtt.su
rm -rf ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/api_lib.cyclo ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/api_lib.d ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/api_lib.o ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/api_lib.su ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/api_msg.cyclo ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/api_msg.d ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/api_msg.o ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/api_msg.su ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/err.cyclo ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/err.d ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/err.o ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/err.su ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/if_api.cyclo ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/if_api.d ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/if_api.o ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/if_api.su ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/netbuf.cyclo ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/netbuf.d ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/netbuf.o ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/netbuf.su ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/netdb.cyclo ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/netdb.d ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/netdb.o ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/netdb.su ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/netifapi.cyclo ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/netifapi.d ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/netifapi.o ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/netifapi.su ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/sockets.cyclo ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/sockets.d ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/sockets.o ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/sockets.su ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/tcpip.cyclo ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/tcpip.d ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/tcpip.o ./Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/tcpip.su
rm -rf ./Core/Startup/startup_stm32h723zgtx.d ./Core/Startup/startup_stm32h723zgtx.o
rm -rf ./Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_rtc_ex.su ./Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_spi.cyclo ./Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_spi.d ./Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_spi.o ./Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_spi.su ./Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_spi_ex.cyclo ./Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_spi_ex.d ./Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_spi_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_spi_ex.su ./Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_tim.cyclo ./Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_tim.d ./Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_tim.o ./Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_tim.su ./Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_tim_ex.cyclo ./Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_tim_ex.d ./Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_tim_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_tim_ex.su ./Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_uart.cyclo ./Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_uart.d ./Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_uart.o ./Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_uart.su ./Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_uart_ex.cyclo ./Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_uart_ex.d ./Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_uart_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_uart_ex.su
rm -rf default.size.stdout template-project.elf template-project.list template-project.map
 
/home/----/----/template-freeRTOS-project/Debug
```

it seems as if rm -rf got prependend to everything by mistake, and lastly the makefile generated by CubeIDE (left untouched from the generation):

```make
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
# Toolchain: GNU Tools for STM32 (11.3.rel1)
################################################################################

-include ../makefile.init

RM := rm -rf

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
-include sources.mk
-include Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/portable/MemMang/subdir.mk
-include Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F/subdir.mk
-include Middlewares/Third_Party/free-rtos/subdir.mk
-include Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/netif/ppp/subdir.mk
-include Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/netif/subdir.mk
-include Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/core/ipv6/subdir.mk
-include Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/core/ipv4/subdir.mk
-include Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/core/subdir.mk
-include Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/apps/tftp/subdir.mk
-include Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/apps/sntp/subdir.mk
-include Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/apps/mqtt/subdir.mk
-include Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/api/subdir.mk
-include LWIP/Target/subdir.mk
-include LWIP/App/subdir.mk
-include Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/subdir.mk
-include Drivers/BSP/Components/lan8742/subdir.mk
-include Core/Startup/subdir.mk
-include Core/Src/subdir.mk
-include objects.mk

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(strip $(CC_DEPS)),)
-include $(CC_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C++_DEPS)),)
-include $(C++_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_UPPER_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_UPPER_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CXX_DEPS)),)
-include $(CXX_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(S_DEPS)),)
-include $(S_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(S_UPPER_DEPS)),)
-include $(S_UPPER_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CPP_DEPS)),)
-include $(CPP_DEPS)
endif
endif

-include ../makefile.defs

OPTIONAL_TOOL_DEPS := \
$(wildcard ../makefile.defs) \
$(wildcard ../makefile.init) \
$(wildcard ../makefile.targets) \


BUILD_ARTIFACT_NAME := template-project
BUILD_ARTIFACT_EXTENSION := elf
BUILD_ARTIFACT_PREFIX :=
BUILD_ARTIFACT := $(BUILD_ARTIFACT_PREFIX)$(BUILD_ARTIFACT_NAME)$(if $(BUILD_ARTIFACT_EXTENSION),.$(BUILD_ARTIFACT_EXTENSION),)

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 
EXECUTABLES += \
template-project.elf \

MAP_FILES += \
template-project.map \

SIZE_OUTPUT += \
default.size.stdout \

OBJDUMP_LIST += \
template-project.list \


# All Target
all: main-build

# Main-build Target
main-build: template-project.elf secondary-outputs

dependents:
    -cd /home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Debug && $(MAKE) all

# Tool invocations
template-project.elf template-project.map: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) /home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Debug/libST-LIB.a /home/-----/-----/template-freeRTOS-project/STM32H723ZGTX_FLASH.ld makefile objects.list $(OPTIONAL_TOOL_DEPS)
    arm-none-eabi-g++ -o "template-project.elf" @"objects.list" $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS) -mcpu=cortex-m7 -T"/home/-----/-----/template-freeRTOS-project/STM32H723ZGTX_FLASH.ld" --specs=nosys.specs -Wl,-Map="template-project.map" -Wl,--gc-sections -static -L"/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Debug" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv5-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -u _printf_float -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -lstdc++ -lsupc++ -Wl,--end-group
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '

default.size.stdout: $(EXECUTABLES) makefile objects.list $(OPTIONAL_TOOL_DEPS)
    arm-none-eabi-size  $(EXECUTABLES)
    @echo 'Finished building: $@'
    @echo ' '

template-project.list: $(EXECUTABLES) makefile objects.list $(OPTIONAL_TOOL_DEPS)
    arm-none-eabi-objdump -h -S $(EXECUTABLES) > "template-project.list"
    @echo 'Finished building: $@'
    @echo ' '

# Other Targets
clean:
    -$(RM) default.size.stdout template-project.elf template-project.list template-project.map
    -@echo ' '

secondary-outputs: $(SIZE_OUTPUT) $(OBJDUMP_LIST)

fail-specified-linker-script-missing:
    @echo 'Error: Cannot find the specified linker script. Check the linker settings in the build configuration.'
    @exit 2

warn-no-linker-script-specified:
    @echo 'Warning: No linker script specified. Check the linker settings in the build configuration.'

.PHONY: all clean dependents main-build fail-specified-linker-script-missing warn-no-linker-script-specified
/home/-----/-----/ST-LIB/Debug/libST-LIB.a:

-include ../makefile.targets
```

We have some CMakeLists.txt already, but they are not stable, so for now we are using the Cube generated makefile. This also restricts us to having to build from the cube, and then push the generated makefile to a remote, when ideally having a CMakeLists.txt would mean not having to run a first instance locally, since the agent could run cmake.

What could be causing this? I assume one of the fixes would be to work with cmake that is more human friendly

I have tried googling around about this command line option but haven't found much.
This is the build configuration tab, I have tried unchecking the option but the same errors occur
[image: build configuration within CubeIDE]

Comment: I have used STM32CubeMX before and it would generate portable makefiles that could be run from anywhere. Maybe try using that instead of STM32CubeIDE.

Comment: I had forgotten that the CubeMX generated makefile based projects, but the whole infrastructure of the project is based on the CubeIDE, so I don't think it is a possibility to switch, but thanks for reminding me of its existence